# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'xx.x.x.xx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna to save some data on my host database on php

```
  <?php
    $username='xxxxx';
    $password='xxxxx';
    try {

    $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=mysql5.000webhost.com;dbname=a4450160_android",$username,$password);

    $result ="INSERT INTO user (fullname, username, password, phone, email)
          VALUES ('zahra', 'mhd', '123', '1234567896', 'zahra@yahoo.com')";
        /*** INSERT ****/
        $count=$dbh->exec($result);
    echo 'success';

    /*** close connection ***/
    $dbh=null;

    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
     }
```

when I test it on my localhost it work fine but 
on the host it does not work.
please help .

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because your MySQL DB does not arrow remote hosts to connect to it,you should change your DB user's privilege.

1. Login with user root.
2. grant option to user xxxxx.`grant insert on db_name.tb_name to 'xxxxx'@'%' identified by 'xxxxx';`
3. `flush privileges;`